# Entity Framework: Saving a collection of enum values

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0

I have one Entity Plan that can have multiple BodyAreas.

```
public class Plan
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TrainningGoal? TrainningGoal { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Video> Videos { get; set; }

    public BodyArea BodyAreas { get; set; }
}
```

I first thought about creation a PlanBodyArea Relation, but then I thought about using the `[Flags]` attribute instead. So I've changed my enum to:

```
[Flags]
public enum BodyArea
{
    Legs = 0,
    Booty = 1,
    Arms = 2,
    Shoulders = 4,
    Bicep = 8,
    Tricep = 16,
    Chest = 32,
    Back = 64,
    Core = 128,
    UpperBody = 256,
    LowerBody = 1024,
    FullBody = 2048
}
```

Problem is that now I don't know how to make the mapping from the Json to ViewModel to my entity.

```
public class PlanViewModel : IViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Duration { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BodyArea> BodyAreas { get; set; }
    public TrainningGoal TrainningGoal { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VideoViewModel>? Videos { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following but of course it doesn't work:

```
        CreateMap<PlanViewModel, Plan>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.BodyAreas, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BodyAreas))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Videos, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Answer (score 2):

A flag would only need a single property not a collection.

`public BodyArea BodyAreas { get; set; }`

To have multiple body areas:

`BodyAreas = BodyArea.Chest | BodyArea.Shoulders;`

To check if a body area is included.  You use the `HasFlag` method to check the `BodyAreas` property.

`BodyAreas.HasFlag(BodyArea.Shoulders);`

[Enum.HasFlag() MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=net-6.0)

On a side note, I would suggest `BodyArea.None = 0`, to allow a default selection.

Comment: but how my json will pass multiple values in the http request?

{ 
id: "",
name: "",
bodyareas: "chest,shoulders,etc"
}

Comment: I'm not sure what library you are using to serialize to json, but an enum flag still has the underlying type of int.  So the list of `BodyAreas` will have a unique integer for each combo, that's why you have to number them the way you do.  `BodyAreas = BodyArea.Booty | BodyArea.Arms;` would have a value of 3 for instance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143175/c-sharp-json-net-render-flags-enum-as-string-array